# trying to style woocommerce dropdown with adding a span inside php code

Tags: php, html, woocommerce

I have PHP code like this:

```
$html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' 
         . selected( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . '>' 
         . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . $price_html ) 
         . '</option>';
```

I want to add `<span class="XXX">` before **$price_html** variable and closing span tag after that, so on I can style the price. I tried the code below but no success:

```
$html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' 
        . selected( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . '>' 
        . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . '<span class="XXX">' . $price_html . '</span>') 
        . '</option>';
```

Any help?

Edit: the code block i am trying to edit:

```
// Utility function to get the price of a variation from it's attribute value
function get_the_variation_price_html( $product, $name, $term_slug ){
    foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ){
        if($variation['attributes'][$name] == $term_slug ){
            return strip_tags( $variation['price_html'] );
        }
    }
}

// Add the price  to the dropdown options items.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'show_price_in_attribute_dropdown', 10, 2);
function show_price_in_attribute_dropdown( $html, $args ) {
    // Only if there is a unique variation attribute (one dropdown)
    if( sizeof($args['product']->get_variation_attributes()) == 1 ) :

    $options               = $args['options'];
    $product               = $args['product'];
    $attribute             = $args['attribute'];
    $name                  = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );
    $id                    = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title( $attribute );
    $class                 = $args['class'];
    $show_option_none      = $args['show_option_none'] ? true : false;
    $show_option_none_text = $args['show_option_none'] ? $args['show_option_none'] : __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' );

    if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {
        $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];
    }

    $html = '<select id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( $class ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" data-show_option_none="' . ( $show_option_none ? 'yes' : 'no' ) . '">';
    $html .= '<option value="">' . esc_html( $show_option_none_text ) . '</option>';

    if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {
        if ( $product && taxonomy_exists( $attribute ) ) {
            $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $attribute, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) {
                    // Get and inserting the price
                    $price_html = get_the_variation_price_html( $product, $name, $term->slug );
                    $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . $price_html ) . '</option>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                $selected = sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ) === $args['selected'] ? selected( $args['selected'], sanitize_title( $option ), false ) : selected( $args['selected'], $option, false );
                // Get and inserting the price
                $price_html = get_the_variation_price_html( $product, $name, $term->slug );
                $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '" ' . $selected . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) . ' = ' . $price_html ) . '</option>';
            }
        }
    }
    $html .= '</select>';

    endif;

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: So, you want to add `span` tag correctly or you would like to have a possibility to style those `option`s? All at once or each one separately based on value?

Comment: I want to add span tag correctly. Let me be more clear, i want to show $price_html inside a span on front page. like below:
<span class="XXX"> $price_html </span>

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you don't see the desired output is in `esc_html()` function. Also, `<span>` tag inside a `<option>` tag doesn't get any CSS styles. You have to place desired `class="XXX"` inside the `<option>` tag.

For now you have something like:

```
<option value="123">escaped_price_html</option>
```

Replace lines:

```
'<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" '
```

with

```
'<option class="XXX" value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" '
```

and

```
. esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . '<span class="XXX">' . $price_html . '</span>')
```

with

```
. esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) .  $price_html)
```

which will change the structure on:

```
<option class="XXX" value="123">escaped_price_html</option>
```

```css
.x{
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<select>
<option value="1"><span class="x">TEXT1</span></option>
<option class="x" value="2"><span>TEXT2</span></option>
<option value="3"><span class="x">TEXT3</span></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you Aksen for responding, unfortunately the way you said is not working in my code. I have edited the question and added the code block to it.

Comment: I see, that because CSS of a `<span>` tag is skipped inside the `<option>` tag. Put your class into `<option>` tag. Updated